# Modifying stochastic meta-descent for variable weight

Tags: machine-learning

In [1], Schraudolph presents an algorithm for updating a weight $w$ and some auxiliary variables $p$ and $v$ given a vector gradient $g$ and another vector "$Cv$".  The update rules attempt to make it so that v goes to $C^{-1}g$ where $C$ could be, for example, the Hessian.  $Cv$ is a vector like $g$ that is passed into the algorithm.

The update rules are:
\begin{align}\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\DeclareMathOperator{\max}{max}
w_{t+1} &= w_t - \diag(p_t)g \\
p_t &= \diag(p_{t-1})\max\left(\frac12, 1 + \mu\diag(v)g\right) \\
v_{t+1} &= \lambda v_t + \diag(p_t) (g - \lambda Cv_t)
\end{align}
where $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are constants.

How would you modify these update rules so that the application of training can be weighted by $0 \le u$ such that it's similar to training $u$ times with the unmodified algorithm.

My first attempt was to replace $g$ with $ug$ and replace $\lambda$ with $\lambda^u$.  I'm looking for insight.

[1]: Schraudolph, N. N. (2002). Fast curvature matrix-vector products for second-order gradient descent. Neural computation, 14(7), 1723–38.

Comment: Is not weighting g by u is enough? Why do you modify lambda?

Comment: @soufanom: I figured that because $λ$ is a forgetting constant, then training multiple times should forget more of $v$.

Comment: @soufanom: You may be interested in the answer below by the author of the paper himself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting idea, but after some thought I would not modify lambda.

In practice, one tries to pick a lambda as close to 1 as possible; there are two reasons why one typically ends up with a lambda < 1:

a) numerical instability of the iteration at lambda = 1;

b) the need to forget old data in nonstationary applications.

In both these contexts, the notion of weighting an input pattern as analogous to training on it a proportional number of times no longer holds up, so modifying lambda here is in my eyes overextending that analogy.